# SQL / Classic ASP - Omit results based on a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I need a bit of help working with a query i have.

Currently im returning a list of results which includes an ID, Amount and SalesID.

An example of my output is as follows:

```
ID: 41008 - SID: 492471 - Amount: 2000
ID: 46705 - SID: 492611 - Amount: 2000
ID: 46705 - SID: 494131 - Amount: 2000
ID: 46705 - SID: 494282 - Amount: 0
ID: 52178 - SID: 489954 - Amount: 5000
ID: 52617 - SID: 493990 - Amount: 2000
ID: 52617 - SID: 494288 - Amount: 0
ID: 54912 - SID: 492579 - Amount: 2000
ID: 57742 - SID: 492892 - Amount: 2000
ID: 58472 - SID: 492685 - Amount: 2000
ID: 58900 - SID: 492720 - Amount: 2000
ID: 59892 - SID: 489873 - Amount: 5000
```

When there is an Amount of 0, I want to omit records with the same ID.

Currently my SQL looks like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM sales WHERE Amount BETWEEN '"&dateBack&"' AND '"&dateForward&"'"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE Paid BETWEEN '"&dateBack&"' AND '"&dateForward&"'" AND Amount <> 0. ADD the condition in where clause to omit Amount value = 0. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: What is the datatype of Amount?

Answer (score 3):

```
"SELECT * FROM sales WHERE Paid BETWEEN '" & dateBack & "' AND '" & dateForward & "' " & _
"AND ID NOT IN " & _
"(SELECT ID FROM sales WHERE Amount = 0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps

```
SELECT * FROM sales 
WHERE Amount BETWEEN '"&dateBack&"' 
AND '"&dateForward&"'"
AND Amount <> 0
```

I think the column name is mentioned as "Paid" instead of "Amount"

Please let me know if you need anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
WHERE amount BETWEEN '"&dateBack&"'
        AND '"&dateForward&"'
    AND Amount <> 0
```

try this. Adding new condition we can remove this `" Amount <> 0 "`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM sales
WHERE  Amount BETWEEN "&dateBack&" AND "&dateForward&""
```

Remove the `'` and try.